# Translation Manager translate option not appearing in Experience Manager

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, translation-manager

We have implemented Tridion Translation Manager and have a configuration similar to the below

01 English Content (Source for translation)

02 Other Language Content (Target for Translation, Inherits from 01)

03 Website Publication (Inherits from 02)

The Translation is working as expected in the CME. We are also able to translate components at the 03 level as we have implemented a Translation Manager plugin that initiates translation at the correct level.

The problem we are having is that experience manager is enabled for the 03 Website Publication. Experience manager has been configured so that it creates components at the 02 level. **When a component is right clicked using the context menu, in experience manager, there is no "Translate" option**.

According to most of the documentation i have read this option should just appear.

EDIT - SDL confirmed that this button should be appearing however after upgrading to 2013 SP1 the button now appears in the context menu. We did not change any Translation manager configuration.

Comment: Hi Chris - can you point to the documentation you refer - it could be possible at a glance that XPM is adhering to the rule of not detecting a target (you don't mention what publication translation metadata exists - i.e. which is the target and source for each publication). You say you've used a plugin to translate from the 03 level - if the publications are configured correctly can you explain why you required a plugin?

Comment: Documentation has been mainly the SDL Live 2013 Documentation for Installing Translation Manger and experience manager.

In my initial comment i state in the brackets which are the target and source publications, are you looking for more information than that? The plugin i mention allows a user to translate content by right clicking and translating at the 03 level and the translation still be created (localized) at the 02 level. This plugin is for user experience... i thought it was worth mentioning as it is not standard.

Comment: So your plugin needs to be extended to work within the context of XPM. 03 has no source or target publication metadata for translation from what I'm reading here - therefore, out of the box, XPM wouldn't be aware.

Comment: The plugin is a variant of the one here - [login required](http://bit.ly/1BAze7m). There is no mention of how to extend this plugin to work with XPM. Would we need to write some events code to handle the TcmId change?

Comment: In fact - it infers it is designed because of / to work with XPM so I wouldn't have expected you to need to extend tit.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but to share what you should see is on the "Manage" tab and in the context menu

[image]

Things to check

- Is context Publication (where the component is being loaded from) configured for Translation
- Is at least one field in the Schema configured as "Translatable"
- Is Translation Manager Connector working as expected in the CME

Comment: In XPM the "BluePrint Context For Components" is the 02 level which is a target for translation. Multiple fields on the configured schema are set as "Translatable". "Translation Manager Connector" is working as expected in the CME.